# JSP class file to HTML

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

hi i am new into jsp and servelet.i know jsp converted to servlet and servelet to class file.i want to know is that how jspfle.class converted into html?and how this response is gone at client level.i know life cyckle of jspbut dont know after .class file got.

I gone through this site [JSP life cycle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_architecture.htm)! and this one [Second link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_life_cycle.htm)!.

But didnt get idea how actually converted from .class file to html.what internally server is doing with .class file to show it to end user/client.

Comment: When a request is received by the application server, the appropriate Servlet is found and the [`service(Request, Response)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#service%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) method is invoked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Jsp` is not getting converted to `html`,rather `jsp` is getting converted into `servlet`,and servlet is generating `html response`.I guess you might have worked on producing an `html response` with the `servlet`.same thing happens there too
[image]

> Servlet------->produces html response
>
> jsp------->converted to servlet--------->produces html response

However saying that `jsp` is getting converted to `html` is wrong

Comment: I know jsp life cycle but i have dout is what if i am set dynamic data as use session value for every time so how this HTML page will generated from this class file??
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

The conversion from .jsp to .java servlet class to .class byte code does not automatically do anything to generate HTML.

It's possible to write servlets and JSPs that do not generate HTML at all.

If you want HTML to be written to the HTTP response you have to write the Java code in the servlet to produce it.

This is a bad 1999 vintage practice.

A better idea is to use JSP with tag libraries like JSTL.  Those generate HTML for you rather nicely.

Comment: How jstl convert servlet to html??
line by line?

Comment: The usual suspects: there's a grammar, a lexer, a parser, an abstract syntax tree, and a code generator.

Comment: ok..That is how all programing language work but i want ans as suppose i am using session and every time html generated from .class of jsp page but how dynamic value it take when html is genereted?

Comment: If you're using JSTL the "T" stands for template.  Like every other templating solution, it substitutes values from the data you specify into appropriate places to generate HTML.  If you're not using JSTL, it simply executes the Java code you put into scriptlets (bad idea) and writes it to the output stream.

Comment: Thanks and one more thing i want to ask is at every request .class of the jsp will run like "java classname" and out of will be the html??

Comment: No, the generation of .class files happens once; the byte code is added to the perm gen just like every other Java .class file.  You can even precompile JSPs if you're worried about that initial hit.